# Proving there exists $ r$ so that the limit is $1 $

Tags: real-analysis

How would I go about proving there exists a real number $ r $ such that:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac {r^x-1}{x}=1$$
*and* actually finding its value?

Comment: You see that the limit is $f'(0)$, where $f(x) = r^x$?

Comment: You know that the answer is $e$. How you prove it depends on the machinery that has been built up to this point in the course.

Comment: @AndréNicolas exactly. That's why I just asked [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784022/defining-the-number-e) question.

Comment: The thing to be *very* careful about is to make sure that the machinery we use does not essentially define $e$ as the number $r$ of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not apply [L'Hopital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)?

We know that, for all $r \neq 0$, we have  $r^x-1 \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. Moreover, $x \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ (!)

The derivative of $r^x-1$, with respect to $x$, is $r^x \ln r$, while the derivative of $x$, w.r.t. $x$ is $1$. Hence

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{r^x-1}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{r^x \ln r}{1} = \ln r \left( \lim_{x \to 0} r^x\right)$$

If $r \neq 0$ then $r^x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$ and hence:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{r^x-1}{x} = \ln r$$

Finally, $\ln r = 1 \iff r = \mathrm{e}$, where $\mathrm{e}$ is the [usual suspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29): $\mathrm{e} \approx 2.718\ldots$

Comment: It's a wonderful answer, but it turns out that my question was ill-posed. _The_ question I really wanted to get an answer to is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784022/defining-the-number-e) one.